# Writing in spreadsheet with Poi and java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am studying POI and I want to find a simple way to write in column B and in each row, certain values.

Right now I have the code below, which reads the spreadsheet, but does not write.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        File CaminhoArquivo = new File("tools\\cnpj.xlsx");

        XSSFWorkbook Planilha = new XSSFWorkbook(CaminhoArquivo);

        XSSFSheet sheet = Planilha.getSheetAt(0);

        int QuantidadeDeLinhas = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println("Quant. de LInhas: " + QuantidadeDeLinhas);
        
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= QuantidadeDeLinhas; i++) {
            
            Row coluna = sheet.getRow(i);
            Cell resultado = coluna.getCell(1);
        
            //Write Line
            resultado.setCellValue("10");
            
        }

        Planilha.close();       
        
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("tools\\cnpj.xlsx"));
        Planilha.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();
        System.out.println("Arquivo Excel editado com sucesso!");
        
    }
```

**ERROR**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> lendoXlsx.xlsx.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:35)

```
//Write Line
    resultado.setCellValue("10");
```

[image: sHEET]

Comment: The [Busy Developers' Guide](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) to POI answers a lot of questions like this. For example, see [Creating Cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three issues in your code.  First, the cell you are writing to does not exist, so you have to create it first by calling the createCell() method:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= QuantidadeDeLinhas; i++) {
    Row coluna = sheet.getRow(i);
    
    coluna.createCell(1);
    Cell resultado = coluna.getCell(1);

    //Write Line
    resultado.setCellValue("10");
    
}
```

Next, you are closing the XSSFWorkbook before trying to write it out.

Finally, you are writing out when the document was created from a File instead of an InputStream.  So, you must either write out to a separate file, or open it from an InputStream.

Here I have moved the workbook close and am writing out to a new file.

```
//Planilha.close();       

FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("tools\\cnpj_new.xlsx"));
Planilha.write(outFile);
outFile.close();
Planilha.close();
System.out.println("Arquivo Excel editado com sucesso!");
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help and especially for detailing what was wrong with my code, so I learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Cells have to exist before you can set a cell value for them. `getCell(1)` returns null because it hasn't been created yet. You can try `getCell(1, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)` or use `createCell(1)` if you don't care that you override the cell.

When using POI i highly recommend to use the interfaces and not the implementations of `XSSFWorkbook` (Interface is `Workbook`) and `XSSFSheet` (Interface is `Sheet`). (For row and cell you are already using the interfaces) Instead of creating your workbook with a constructor you can use `WorkbookFactory.create`. This way you're code will work for xls and xlsx. There are some cases where you need the implementation instead of the interface, but 99% of the time you don't.